# unable to pass selectInput to output$table summary in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my first month using Shiny.
I want to create a simple app to be used by my school to show a summary of passed and failed students. 
Here's a reproducible example and I'll point to the error:

```
library(shiny)

Physiology <- c(49, 64, 74, 84)
Physiology2 <- ifelse(Physiology < 50, "Fail", "Pass")

Biochemistry <- c(49, 46, 74, 84)
Biochemistry2 <- ifelse(Biochemistry < 50, "Fail", "Pass")

Second <- data.frame(cbind(Physiology, Physiology2, Biochemistry, Biochemistry2))

Second$Physiology <- as.numeric(as.character(Second$Physiology))
Second$Biochemistry <- as.numeric(as.character(Second$Biochemistry))
```

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
            selectInput("Subject", 
                        "Choose Subject", 
                        choices=list("Physiology2", "Biochemistry2")),
            tableOutput("table")
            )
```

Server:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      output$table <- renderTable(as.table(summary({input$Subject})))
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I receive the following error

```
'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

The issue here is that

```
input$Subject
```

in the server isn't passed. 
When I manually do

```
Second$Physiology2
```

The table is produced normally.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Comment: One additional note: `as.table` in your server is redundant; `summary` already returns an object of the same class as `as.table` (you can compare the resulting values using `class(summary(...))` and `class(as.table(summary(...)))`. Better yet, use `identical(summary(...), as.table(summary(...)))`.

Comment: Thank you for your note. In the app, when I used `summary` only it returned one column with the numbers only. However, when I used `as.table(summary ...())` it produced full table. You're right in R, both are the same, however in Shiny for a reason I'm not aware of it, this was what happened for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you pass a name taken from input, not data. So your code is equivalent to:

```
as.table(summary("Physiology2"))
```

All you have to do here is subset the data:

```
output$table <- renderTable(as.table(summary(Second[[input$Subject]])))
```